# Best way to get the dropped records after using "dropDuplicates" function in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a dataframe which contains duplicate records based on a column. My requirement is to drop duplicates based on the column and perform certain operation on unique records. And also identify the duplicate record based on column and save it to hbase for audit purposes.

input file:

```
A,B
1,2
1,3
2,5

Dataset<Row> datasetWithDupes=session.read().option("header","true").csv("inputfile");

//drop dupliactes on column A
Dataset<Row> datasetWithoutDupes = datasetWithDupes.dropDuplicates("A")
```

A dataset is required with dropped record. I have tried 2 options

- Using except function

  `Dataset<Row> droppedRecords = datasetWithDupes.except("datasetWithoutDupes ")`
  this should contain the dropped records

  - Using the ranking function directly without using "dropDuplicates"

`datasetWithDupes.withColumn("rank", functions.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("A").seq()).orderBy("B").seq())))`

then filtering based on the rank to get the duplicate records.

Is there any faster way to get the duplicated records, because I am using it in streaming application and most of the processing time(50%) is getting elapsed on finding the duplicate records and saving it to hbase table. I have batch interval of 10 sec and around 5 sec is getting spent for the task for filtering the duplicate record.

Please suggest to achieve in faster way.

Comment: How about antijoin? Have u given that a try ?

Comment: @Aaron, No i have not tried. Let me try and update. Thanks for the suggestion